HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3
I wrote a FASTapi program that I used to run it with ngrok library to create external ports for it as I run it on Colab. Then I dockerized it without ngrok like this:
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME FastAPIApp

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

and the requirements.txt is:
fastapi
uvicorn
python-multipart
pydub
nest-asyncio
audonnx 
audinterface

so, I dockerized it with: docker build -t my-fastapi-app . command and then ran it with:docker run -p 8000:8000 my-fastapi-app. It run but as soon as I request it by IDLE python with:
import requests

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'
files = {'file': open('C:\\Users\\Z\\Desktop\\v\\f.m4a', 'rb')}

response = requests.post(url, files=files)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)

It doesn't show any log but the IDLE shows these errors and doesn't work at all:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 497, in _make_request
    conn.request(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 395, in request
    self.endheaders()
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 243, in connect
    self.sock = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002C8B47DE610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002C8B47DE610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\requestapi.py", line 6, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002C8B47DE610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context')


I also take a look at this:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1/
would you please help me? I'm on windows.

0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "all interfaces".  In a Docker context it's important that your service listen on it, but it doesn't make sense to connect to it in a URL.  Do you need some other hostname here?  Perhaps see Networking in Compose in the Docker documentation for more details on what hostnames might be available to you.

@DavidMaze tnx but can u say it simpler and exactly what should I do? Do you say I should change this part: CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]? what should I write instead?

If you're running this from outside a container, on the same host, does setting url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' work any better?  (Compare to [OSError WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context.)

I tried it before maybe sth else has happened, but now surprisingly worked, tnx a lot. If u want U answer it or after some hours I will @DavidMaze. By the way how will u find these answers?
